# Is there a way to control which frame an APNG starts from using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, apng

I'm trying to make an APNG play on mouseover, then get the frame the APNG is on on mouseout, then use that frame to play a reversed APNG so that there's a smooth transition. I tried searching around but couldn't really find much.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```html
<img src="regular_png.png" id="apng">
```

```js
document.getElementById("apng").onmouseover = function() {
  this.src = "apng1.png";
}
document.getElementById("apng").onmouseout = function() {
  // Get the current frame the apng is on
  this.src = "apng2.png";
  // Start apng2.png from total # of frames - current frame from apng1.png
}
```